# Jquery and Asp.Net MVC passing Obejct to Controller through Jquery Ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass Object from Jquery to asp.net mvc controller action. The parameter is always null. what is my mistake?

**Creating object for countries**

```
var selectedCountries = [];

var id = 1;

$(".countriesSelection").find('span').each(function() {
  var countryName = $(this).text();
  var profile1 = {};
  profile1.id = id;
  profile1.countryName = countryName;

  selectedCountries.push(profile1)
});

console.log(selectedCountries);
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countriesSelection">
  <span>India</span>
  <span>USA</span>
  <span>China</span>
  <span>Japan</span>
</div>
```

**calling controller**

```
selectedCountries = (Object.assign({}, selectedCountries));

            $.ajax({
                url: "AddCountries",
                type: "POST",
                data: { "selectedCountries": selectedCountries },
                traditional: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log("Something went wrong.." + err.status);
                }
            });

    });
```

**Asp.net MVC Controller**

```
  [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult AddCountries(List<ProfileEntity> selectedCountries){
//my c# code comes here but selectedCountries Parameter is always null

}
```

**Profile Entity**

```
public class ProfileEntity
    {
        [Required]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string countryName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({ "selectedCountries": selectedCountries }),` (where `selectedCountries` is the array) and add `contentType: 'application/json'` (note `traditional: true,` only applies to arrays of simple types, not to arrays of complex objects)

Comment: Object.assign I am trying to convert array to Object

Comment: You method expects an array of `ProfileEntity` therefore you need to send it an array, not an object

Comment: Remove `traditional: true,` and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an array like this in `selectedCountries` variable,

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "countryName": "India"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "countryName": "USA"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "countryName": "China"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "countryName": "Japan"
}]
```

When you execute this line

```
selectedCountries = (Object.assign({}, selectedCountries));
```

it will reset the value of `selectedCountries` to to an **object** (not an array)

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": 1,
        "countryName": "India"
    },
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "countryName": "USA"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 1,
        "countryName": "China"
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 1,
        "countryName": "Japan"
    }
}
```

That does not match with your action method parameter type. For model binding to work, the structure of the data you are sending should match the structure of the parameter type, along with the property names. That means if your server action method expects an array, you should send an array, not an object

You should send the array. Use `JSON.stringify` to create the json string of the array and send that while specifying your content-type as `application/json`

This should work. In the below code snippet, i also changed the way you were populating the array using the `$.map` method (Your current implementation will absolutely work, but i like less code)

```
var id = 1;

var spans = $("div.countriesSelection").find('span');
var selectedCountries = $.map(spans, function (item)
{
    return { id: id, countryName: $(item).text() };
});

$.ajax({
    url: "AddCountries",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(selectedCountries),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result)
    {
        console.log('result', result);
    },
    error: function (err)
    {
        console.log("Something went wrong.." + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

Comment: what will be datatype for controller parameter?

Comment: Same as what you have in the question. It should work `public ActionResult AddCountries(List<ProfileEntity> selectedCountries)`

Comment: I still see countries object as  "0": {
        "id": 1,
        "countryName": "India"
    },

Comment: Where are you seeing it ?

Comment: In jquery selected countries object

Comment: Are you sure you removed the Object.assign line ? See the working version here http://jsbin.com/sowubinuwu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Switching to map is not necessary. your old code to populate the array will still work.

Comment: It gave me correct jquery object but it is not coming to controller parameter. I tried this also but no luck.  data: JSON.stringify({ "selectedCountries": selectedCountries })

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169380/discussion-between-kurkula-and-shyju).

Comment: You need to follow the code in answer. Please read the code carefully. ( The code in my answer does not have anything like `JSON.stringify({ "selectedCountries": selectedCountries })`

Comment: It should be `data: JSON.stringify(selectedCountries),`